# program to find the count of each word in a para

Tags: c

i am trying to find count of each word in a para but i am not able to get it done...

so can any one tell me how to do that..

Example Input----

```
Hi stack over flow is a good forum.There will be many experts in stack overflow .
```

ouput--

```
Hi---1
stack-2
overflow-2
is---1
a---1
good---1

...
...
```

in this way i want to get output.

This is my code...but it is not complete...after that i got struck to proceed

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define NULL 0

struct wordcount
{
    char *s;
    int count;
    struct wordcount next;
}

struct checkletter
{
    char alph;
    struct wordcount next;
}

main()
{
    char *c;
    int hash[26],len,i,k=0,intm[100];
    struct checkletter complete[26];
    for(r=0;r<25;r++)
    {
        complete[r].alph=r+97;
        complete[r].next=NULL;
    }
    printf("Enter the para :");
    gets(s);
    len=strlen(s);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {       
        k=0;
        if(c[i]==' ')
        {
            for(j=i;j>m;j--)
            {
                intm[k]=c[i];
                s1=intm;
                k++;
            }
            m=k;
            hastlet=s1[0];

            for(t=0;t<26;t++)
            {
                if(complete[t].alph==hastlet)
                {
                    if(complete[t].next==NULL)
                        complete[t].next=
                }
```

Comment: That's not how we like to work here.  Show us what you've tried and we'll help you get it working.

Comment: We need to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: i am trying using structure and linked lists ...but i got struck and i am not able to move further.

Comment: @satheesh: That's fine, it can be made to work, but it's not even close to optimal (it's O(n), `n` is the number of words in the input stream, to find the right bucket in the linked list to increment the count for).

Comment: Show us. You can edit your question via the edit link just below the tags. If we can see what you've done, we can tell you what's not working and probably offer other helpful tips along the way. But we can't do it for you.

Comment: @Ninefingers: It's not that we can't, it's that we won't.

Comment: @satheesh: Oh, come on. Just dumping code on us, and expecting us to spend the time to compile it, run it, debug it, etc. is asking way too much. Ask very specific very pointed questions.

Comment: @Jason I guess what I mean is we can't do the learning part for him.

Comment: sorry sir..i will work on it further and i will come to u with any specific question ..if didnt get

Comment: @Ninefingers: Okay, that's fair, and true.

Comment: @satheesh I've made what I can of the code readable. It doesn't look complete to me - if I've got it badly wrong feel free to edit it. One note though, if you're pasting from a source editor, configure your editor to convert tabs to spaces. It'll save you a lot of trouble with the formatting tools. Tabs really don't work well.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a sketch:

1. Parse the paragraph into a token of words
2. Maintain a map from hash codes to counters, being careful that collisions are possible
3. For each word in the paragraph, hash the word to an integer
4. Again, being careful that collisions are possible, increment the corresponding count
5. Run through the hash table spitting out the words and the counts

Beyond that, if you have a specific question about your own implementation of the above, let us know and we can try to help. We are not going to write your code for you, though.